# AVCaptureSession with multiple Outputs?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I'm currently developing an iOS app that applies CoreImage to the camera feed in order to take photos and videos, and I've run into a bit of snag.

Up till now I've been using **AVCaptureVideoDataOutput** to obtain the sample buffers and manipulate them with CoreImage, and then displayed a simple preview, as well as using it to capture photos and saving them.

When I tried to implement Video Recording, by writing the SampleBuffers to a video as I received them from the **AVCaptureVideoDataOutput**, it had a very slow frame rate (probably because of the other image relating processing that was going on).

So I was wondering, is it possible to have an **AVCaptureVideoDataOutput** and a AVCaptureMoveFileOutput going on the same AVCaptureSession simultaneously?

I gave it a quick go, and found that when I added the extra output, my AVCaptureVideoDataOutput stopped receiving information.

If I can get it working, I'm hoping it means that I can simply use the 2nd output to record video at high frame rates, and do post-processing on the video after the user has stopped recording.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Were you using AVAssetWriter to write the image out to a MOV/MP4? I do use a custom OpenGL image processing engine and can still record at 30fps. I assumed CoreImage would be OpenGL backed for efficiency. I do suspect that what is holding you back is the display of the images. Are you using OpenGL to render the images, or are you using some other API (possibly CPU based)?

Comment: did you find a workable solution?

Comment: @SteveMcFarlin He said he was using AVCaptureMoveFileOutput; that's different than AVAssetWriter.

Answer (score 4):

It's easier than you'd think.

See: [AVCamDemo](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html)

1. Capture data using AVCaptureVideoDataOutput.
2. Create a new dispatch queue before recording, eg. recordingQueue: `recordingQueue =
   dispatch_queue_create("Movie Recording Queue",
   DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);`
3. In the captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection: delegate
       method, capture the samplebuffer, retain it, and in the recording
       queue, write it to the file:

   ```
   -(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection {    

       CFRetain(sampleBuffer);

       dispatch_async(recordingQueue, ^{

           if (assetWriter) {

               if (connection == videoConnection) {
                   [self writeSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer ofType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
               } else if (connection == audioConnection) {
                   [self writeSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer ofType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
               }

           }

           CFRelease(sampleBuffer);        
       });
   }

       - (void) writeSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer ofType:(NSString *)mediaType
       {
           CMTime presentationTime = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer);

           if ( assetWriter.status == AVAssetWriterStatusUnknown ) {

               if ([assetWriter startWriting]) {
                   [assetWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:presentationTime];
               } else {
                   NSLog(@"Error writing initial buffer");
               }
           }

           if ( assetWriter.status == AVAssetWriterStatusWriting ) {

               if (mediaType == AVMediaTypeVideo) {
                   if (assetWriterVideoIn.readyForMoreMediaData) {

                       if (![assetWriterVideoIn appendSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer]) {
                           NSLog(@"Error writing video buffer");
                       }
                   }
               }
               else if (mediaType == AVMediaTypeAudio) {
                   if (assetWriterAudioIn.readyForMoreMediaData) {

                       if (![assetWriterAudioIn appendSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer]) {
                           NSLog(@"Error writing audio buffer");
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   ```

Comment: please, convert to Swift 4

Comment: Why are you using AVAssetWriter? The question made no reference to this and your answer doesn't;t explain where you defined assetWriter.