# Recording video using AVFoundation Swift

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I created a AVCaptureSession and manipulate each frame (morphing) the users face,adding layers etc. How can i turn those frames into a video that can be saved to the camera roll?

Here's how i set up `AVCaptureSession`

```
func setupCapture() {

    let session : AVCaptureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480


    let device : AVCaptureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
    let deviceInput : AVCaptureDeviceInput = try! AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device)


    if session.canAddInput(deviceInput) {
        session.addInput(deviceInput)
    }

    stillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()


    videoDataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()

    let rgbOutputSettings = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: NSNumber(unsignedInt: kCMPixelFormat_32BGRA)]

    videoDataOutput.videoSettings = rgbOutputSettings
    videoDataOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true

    videoDataOutputQueue = dispatch_queue_create("VideoDataOutputQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)
    videoDataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: videoDataOutputQueue)

    if session.canAddOutput(videoDataOutput) {
        session.addOutput(videoDataOutput)
    }
    videoDataOutput.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo).enabled = false

    effectiveScale = 1.0

    previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: session)
    previewLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect
    let rootLayer : CALayer = previewView.layer
    rootLayer.masksToBounds = true
    previewLayer.frame = rootLayer.bounds
    rootLayer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
    session.startRunning()
}
```

Than i use the `CMSampleBuffer` to get a `CIImage` which i add my effects to.

```
func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

    let pixelBuffer : CVPixelBufferRef = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)!
    let attachments : CFDictionaryRef = CMCopyDictionaryOfAttachments(kCFAllocatorDefault, pixelBuffer, CMAttachmentMode( kCMAttachmentMode_ShouldPropagate))!

    let ciImage : CIImage = CIImage(CVPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer, options: attachments as? [String : AnyObject])
```

How can i record video doing this?

Comment: I've got same question? Have you found a solution?

Comment: Nothing yet, let me know in case you do.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution to your problem. I too am working in Swift and had the same question. I'm thankful you posted this question because it helped me a lot. I was able to successfully process frames and then write them to the camera roll. I have not perfected it, but it is possible.

It turns out once you start messing around with AVCaptureDataOutput you allegedly lose the ability to use AVCaptureMovieFileOutput see discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968879/simultaneous-avcapturevideodataoutput-and-avcapturemoviefileoutput?rq=1).

A concise solution to your problem can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058891/avcapturesession-with-multiple-outputs/22037685#22037685). This is the version I implemented. Feed the sampleBuffer to the AVAssetWriterInput object.

A more verbose [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944083/can-use-avcapturevideodataoutput-and-avcapturemoviefileoutput-at-the-same-time/4944594#4944594) to solving the problem describes exactly what parts (i.e. AVAssetWriter, AVAssetWriterInput and outSettings etc..) are needed and what they look like.

The links I posted are in obj-c but can be translated into swift. I hope you have already solved your problem.

Comment: Thank you, i still haven't found a proper way to get it done, so i'll check the links out. Let me know if you find anything else.